# How did mathematics come to use $\log(x)$ and not $\ln(x)$

Tags: logarithm

**Question:** How and why did the discipline of mathematics come to use $\log(x)$ and not $\ln(x)$ in its writing - papers, books, teaching?

Clearly $\ln(x)$ is unambiguously $\log_e(x)$, but $\log(x)$ is ambiguous.

Almost all textbooks, papers and informal formats like blogs and YouTube videos use $\log(x)$ and assume base $e$.

Comment: The notation "ln" is a recent innovation.  Mathematicians used to (and most still do) write "log" for the natural logarithm.  "ln" first used 1893, "log" first used 1647, but "Log." used 1624.  See https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathsym/functions/

Comment: I understand that use of $\log$ instead of $\ln$ may be a sign of academic snobbishness. A sniffy-nosed colleague of mine stated categorically that using $\ln$ was unprofessional and showed that its user was unsophisticated and had obviously never risen further than a mediocre grade at school. As a consequence I use $\ln$ universally.

Comment: Is it really ``the discipline of mathematics"? It seems to me the use of ln versus log  is a cultural thing, with log dominant in the US. In my university education in Eastern Europe at the end of the last century, ln for natural logarithm was alive and kicking.

Comment: @MargaretFriedland the custom in Eastern Europe is more mixed now. In the last 10+ years in Russia I often saw the notation ln used in writing at the blackboard (a culture shock the first time, coming from the US), but in some recently published pure math books there I have found log.  I wonder if a more common habit of writing papers in English has made log in place of ln more accepted.

Answer (score 3):

For me, handwritten especially, but also typeset, "ln" is easier to mis-read than "log". And since I do not ever use any logarithm but "base $e$", (except, rarely, base $2$ for some information-theory things maybe), there is simply no ambiguity.

It's true, it is easier to start kids with logs base $10$, and in calculus make the distinction to/from "ln", ... but that is a transitional phase, I think.

(Financial computations do also use logs base $e$, for reasons of natural phenomena! But, one way or another, almost no people have any reason to directly worry about which logarithm was intended...)

Comment: Thanks Paul. Can I ask how typeset "ln" can be misread? What are the other possibilities for interpretation?

Comment: @Penelope, well, the "l" in the "ln" may suggest that it's a capital "i", or a numeral "one". Sure, a little concentration can usually resolve that... but there's nothing at all similar to "log"... When scanning things, ease of such details makes a difference, for me. Maybe not for others. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett In handwriting, if one uses joined-up writing, it is difficult to mistake $\text l$ for $\text I$. Unfortunately the concern is more about the universal use of sans-serif fonts in computers, coupled with a careless ignorance about using professional typesetting software that allow one to mistake $\ln$ with $\text {In}$. Seriously, whose stupid idea was it to standardise on Arial instead of something with serifs like TNR? They deserve to be kicked around the world by the backside. :-)

Comment: @PrimeMover, yes, in any sort of cursive, the (in TeX) $\ell$ is easily distinguishable. But, in modern times wherein many people never use cursive, block-printing or stick-printing leaves "ell" as just a vertical slash... and "one" is a vertical slash... and upper-case "i" is a vertical slash... and an uncrossed "t"... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Bah. the youth of today. No respect for their elders. When I was a young man we were expected to communicate clearly. Just a minute, there's someone on my lawn. "Oy! Gerroff ..."